# Dice Roll Probability Question

Tags: probability, dice

When five standard dice are rolled together what is the probability that three come up 2 and two come up 4?

Is there a trick with pascal's triangle that can help solve this? If so what is it? Thoughts and suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  what is the probability of getting $2,2,2,4,4$ in that order?  How many ways are there to pick $3$ slots out of $5$?

Comment: You need the binomial coefficient $\binom{5}{3}$ , which is the number of ways to choose $3$ out of $5$. Divide this by $6^5$ to get the probability of the "full house". You do not need Pascal's triangle, but you can use it to determine the binomial coefficients.